# ubuntu 14.04 installation problem on win 7

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 using wubi ,I had a 12.04  installation on this laptop.Some how I have removed the old one and now installing new.I downloaded 
Ubuntu 14.04-1-desktop-amd64 ISO and extracted wubi from it kept both ISO and wubi in same folder,

I noticed each time wubi will start downloading ISO from internet.I let it do for 2-4 days some how thir process did not result in any fruitful thing.

Now I found on some thread people facing this issue will disconnect their internet connection and wubi installer will start installation from downloaded ISO, in my case also I disconnected lan wire from laptop and then using wubi installation began.

But at the end when I boot then I am getting errors
as / is not found/not mounted press I to ignore S to Skip or M for manual recovery.
 /tmp is not found press I to ignore S to Skip or M for manual recovery.

I do not know how to manually fix it. Igonoring or skipping the process leads me to borne shell based login prompt with no X window interface at all. How ever during install it downloaded every thing it possibly could because once installation had begun I had connected the lanwire. After multiple such installation attempts I have finally failed to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my system. (12.04 was running fine I have lost that now) .What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove all and install 14.04, Then make a bootable DVD or USB drive and boot from it, This will be easiest way to install...

Comment: I do not have a working CD/DVD ROM neither USB option is there for me.

Comment: Then you should arrange that